# Datepicker - remove div if saturday is picked

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Hi im trying to remove times when Saturday is picked from datepicker
but also display chosen date

see my jsfiddle to understand what im trying to achieve

http://jsfiddle.net/finestice/v4327/66/

I know its something to do with the below code

```
onSelect: doSomething,

onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("input[name='date']").val(dateText);
    }
```

im still learning jquery so im not sure whats going wrong

please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please add the code from your fiddle to your question. You can do it as a "snippet" so everybody has instant feedback about whats going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your idea correctly, try to use this `onSelect` function:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  $("input[name='date']").val(dateText);
  var day = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay).getDay();
  if (day === 6) $(".timeAvai").hide(); else $(".timeAvai").show();
}
```

and place text `Your Availability Is` inside `.timeAvai`.

Comment: Thank you curveball... Works great, just what i wanted :)